# Possible to initialize static variable by calling function

Tags: c

Is this possible?

```
static bool initialize()
{
  TRC_SCOPE_INIT(...); 
  ...
}

static bool initialized = initialize();
```

To make a very long story short, I need to call a series of macros (to initialize debugging messages) as early as possible (before thread X is started, and I don't have the ability to know when thread X is started).

Comment: Can you insert a call to `pthread_once(3)` in your `main()` routine?

Comment: @KingsIndian: `bool` is valid in C99 with the `stdbool.h` header.

Comment: @icktoofay It wasn't specified as c99 anyway, so added c++ tag.

Comment: @KingsIndian: C++ is more of a leap than C99.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to tag something C99 for it to be considered C99.  That is the **old** standard, which _is_ more widely available than the new C2011 standard for the next year or two.  If something is only for C89, then it needs special treatment (unless the platform is tagged Windows, where the main compiler is retrograde and does not support C99 properly).

Comment: This is a needless argument. Adding c++ is not going to mess anything here except it will attract answers for both or better answers. Besides, it's been removed already.

Comment: Adding c++ tag is very harmful. It will result in getting c++ answers which are not applicable to C.

Answer (score 6):

When I originally looked at the question, it was tagged both C and C++.  The code could be C or C++ because `bool` is a type in C99 and C11, just as it is in C++ (almost; in C, you need the `<stdbool.h>` header to get the name `bool`).

The answers for the two tags are:

- In C++, yes.
- In C, no.

They are not the same language.  If you need a demonstration, this is as good an example as any.

Comment: The question was tagged only `c` when it was originally posted. @KingsIndian added the `c++` tag because of the `bool`, but I reverted that edit because `bool` is valid in C99 and there was no indication from the original post that it was anyhow C++ related.

Comment: @icktoofay: thanks for the clarification; I've adjusted my answer slightly to recognize the changes.

Comment: for those who are curious, (a) C++11 lets you use constexpr, (b) there is surprisingly little compiler support for it

Comment: Regardless of how the question is or was tagged, having the explanation for both the C++ and C behaviors is appropriate and makes this a better answer than having only the C answer. I think the fact that C++ readily permits this is a source of confusion for people who then want to do it in C.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using GCC (or clang), you can use `__attribute__((constructor))`:

```
static bool initialized = false;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void initialize(void) {
    initialized = true;
    // do some other initialization
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // initialize will have been run before main started
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be alright provided the "stuff" you are initializing is defined in the same translation unit as the call to the function that initializes it.  In addition, it must be defined above the call site.  Otherwise you risk undefined behavior due to use of uninitialized values.

One way to get around this is to use a pointer instead.  A statically initialized pointer is compiled into the executable image, so there's no risk of undefined behavior if it's used by statics defined in other translation units.  In your static initialization function you dynamically allocate the "stuff" and set the pointer to point to it so you can access it later.

Answer (score 1):

(Since you mentioned threads, I'm going to assume you have POSIX thread functions at your disposal.)

The `pthread_once` function exists for this exact purpose. Anywhere you need to be sure `initialize` has already been called, write:

```
pthread_once(&init_once, initialize);
```

where `init_once` is defined with static storage duration, and possibly with external linkage if needed, as `pthread_once_t init_once`.